# $\int\frac{Re(z)}{2z-i}dz$ along unit circle

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I want to use Cauchy's Integral Formula to evaluate $\int\frac{Re(z)}{2z-i}dz$ along the unit circle of centre 0. But $Re(z)$ is not holomorphic, is it? If not, what can I do to fix it and apply Cauchy's Integral Formula?

Comment: Hint: On the unit circle, $\bar{z}=\frac{1}{z}$

Comment: It can be done using Complex Analysis, but I don't see how to do it using Cauchy's Integral Formula, since $\operatorname{Re}$ is not holomorphic.

Comment: @NinadMunshi I don't see how that helps

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos See the posted solution.

Comment: @MarkViola I did not think of that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that $z\mapsto\mathrm{Re}(z)$ is not holomorphic.

However, on the unit circle $\{|z|=1\}$:
$$
\text{Re}(z)=\frac{z+\overline{z}}{2}=\frac12\left(z+\frac1z\right)
$$
So
$$
\frac{\textrm{Re}(z)}{2z-i}=\frac12\cdot\left(\frac{z}{2z-i}+\frac{1}{(2z-i)z}\right)
$$
By linearity of the integrals, you can apply the Cauchy integral formula to find
$$
\int_\gamma \frac{z}{2z-i}\;dz,\quad \int_\gamma\frac{1}{z(2z-i)}\;dz\;.
$$
To find the second integral, it may be convenient to apply the residue theorem.

---

As Jose mentioned in the [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4299426/int-fracrez2z-idz-along-unit-circle/4299450#comment8953968_4299450) below, one can apply partial fraction decomposition
$$
\frac{1}{z(2z-i)}=\frac{A}{z}+\frac{B}{2z-i}
$$
so that one can again apply the Cauchy integral formula directly to find the second integral.

Comment: In order to deal with the second integral, the equality$$\frac1{z(2z-i)}=\frac iz-\frac{2i}{2z-i}$$can also be used.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: sure, that's a good point! Thanks. I will add that.